# PL/SQL Oracle - Encountered the symbol “end-of-file”

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to make a procedure which gives grants to users on a certain type of objects

Here's what I did

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE grants AS
DECLARE
   Cursor c IS select OBJECT_NAME as view_name from all_objects where object_type in ('VIEW');

BEGIN
    FOR tmp in c
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL on ' || tmp.view_name ||  ' TO my_users';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But I'm getting an 'end-of-file' symbole encountered [...]' error...

Do you guys have an idea to make this procedure work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `DECLARE`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE grants AS
  2      CURSOR c  IS
  3          SELECT OBJECT_NAME AS view_name
  4            FROM all_objects
  5           WHERE object_type IN ('VIEW');
  6  BEGIN
  7      FOR tmp IN c
  8      LOOP
  9          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL on ' || tmp.view_name || ' TO my_users';
 10      END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Comment: All right that's what I thought, my problem should be somwhere else. I copied/paste exactly what you've wrote but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: How are you running it? SQLPLUS, some other tool?

Comment: I'm trying to run it with DbVisualizer Pro 9.0.8

Comment: I don't know this tool, but maybe the issue is in the way you have to run plsql code from within the tool. What if you run it in SQLPLUS?

Comment: I've found the issue. I've removed the semicolons and the procedure was created successfully, then I had to edit it and re-add the semicolons, and it finally worked. Weird issue... Anyway, thank you